# `panting` is only for dog? about a swear word

Tags: idiom-request

My translation assignment again.

Does the word `panting` is used only for animals?

This is the story; A girl is blaming(insulting) her brother`s girlfriend because of sex noise everynight.

`Im goint to let you off because of my brother.
 You ------.`

That should be a swear word like you bitch, but 
I can`t find a good example.

You panting girl???? Why you whore?? horny girl???

That looks weird enough. X(

Im sorry for asking you a swear word, but 
could you tell me something that is frequently used from teenage girl? (The girl in the book is almost 17)

And as I told you the situation, there should be some
related implication of sex noise

Comment: Panting wouldn't be a word to use.  Are you looking for a word that would disapprove of her brother's behavior as well, or not?  If you call her something that has to do with unacceptable sexual promiscuity (such as whore) then you are by implication also putting down her brother.  If you don't care about that, then whore is perhaps the most likely word the girl would use.  "Nympho" would be a less negative word, simply implying that her sex drive is too high.  Now, you might also consider "I'm going to let you off as a favor to my brother."

Answer (score 2):

In English, *panting* isn't only used for a dog. When applied to people, though, I usually think of athletes:

> *The sprinters were panting at the finish line.*

The word *panting* can be used in a sexual context, too, but I think that would refer to the noise itself, more than to the parties involved. For example:

> *I heard a lot of panting in the room last night.*

could be a mild way to say: "I think I heard you two having sex last night."

If you want a word that is both vulgar and insulting, you might consider *slut*:

> I'm going to let you off because of my brother.
>   *You slut!*

The word *slut* is relatively common, and it's generally considered to be an insult toward a woman for perceived promiscuity.